# How can I plot this complicated integral in R?

Tags: r

I am currently struggling with a complicated function which I want to draw in R. Basically it is a combination of distribution and other dependent probability, so I have to modify a normal distribution.

The final formula will look something like this:

[image: integral]

How can I draw it in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the equation, so use `stats::integrate` to calculate the definite integral term in your `f(x)` definition.   Then, as an example:  `plot(0:1000, f(0:1000),t='l')` .

Comment: Neat! I didn't know `integrate` can deal with infinite bounds.

Answer (score 5):

Since the integral is the cumulative PDF of a normal distribution (except for the missing normalization factor) you can calculate it with `pnorm`.

```
sf <- 1
mf <- 0
f <- function(x) 1/(2*sf^2*pi)*exp(-.5*((x-mf)/sf)^2) *
                 (1 - sf*sqrt(2*pi)*pnorm(x, mf, sf))
curve(f, from=-2, to=2)
```

The `sf*sqrt(2*pi)` factor is to compensate for the missing normalization. I am not 100% sure I got the mathematics correct though, so please verify it yourself too.

**Edit:** As [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) pointed out the first part of `f` can be simplified with `dnorm`, making the code more readable.

```
f <- function(x) dnorm(x, mf, sf)/(sqrt(2*pi)*sf) *
                 (1 - sf*sqrt(2*pi)*pnorm(x, mf, sf))
```

[image: curve]

Comment: This is a great solution, thanks a lot :) But anyhow, how can i enter an integral like this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "enter" here. Plot the integral or translate the equation into R code? I just did both, so if you have some other function you just have to modify the code above. If you have a non-standard integral you should go for `integrate()` that @Carl suggested, instead of `pnorm()`. Or do you want to draw the equation into the plot area?

Comment: I think you can simplify this slightly by using `dnorm` for the first factor (although you will have to adjust the normalization factor there too)

Comment: @BenBolker: I thought `pnorm` divides with `sqrt(2*pi)*sf` by default, but in our case we don't want that, so I multiplied with it to neutralize.

Comment: I meant the `dnorm` part -- the OP has a factor of `1/(2*pi*sf^2)` out front, `dnorm` only gives us `1/sqrt(2*pi*sf^2)` ...